# find an item with a mouse when map moves in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game where the player is centered in the middle of a surface. This surface moves around instead of this player I want to be able to add object such as swords. I have a problem I can get the mouse cursor over the object when I first start the game, but when I move around putting the mouse cursor over the object doesn't do anything and in another area, it does what it's supposed to do. I think as the map moves it goes off screen changing the position of the mouse falling on the object. I created this sample to show what I mean

```
import pygame

width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
world = pygame.Surface((20 * 32, 40 * 32))
itemPos = (4,8)
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(40):
        pygame.draw.rect(world, (255,0,0), (x * 32,y * 32,32,32), 2)
x,y = 0,0
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        y += 10
    if key[pygame.K_s]:
        y -= 10
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        x += 10
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        x -= 10
    screen.blit(world, (x,y))
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.draw.rect(world, (0,255,0), (itemPos[0] * 32,itemPos[1] * 32,20,20))
    if mouse[0] > itemPos[0] * 32 and mouse[0] < (itemPos[0] * 32) + 32:
        if mouse[1] > itemPos[1] * 32 and mouse[1] < (itemPos[1] * 32) + 32:
            print("Mouse is over item")
    pygame.display.update()
```

the red hollow squares are just the map. Then the smaller green square is the object that I test if the cursor is over. try the code and move around a bit then try placing the cursor over the green object to get `mouse is over item`. That's basically what I want to achieve but can't figure out

Comment: I don't understand I don't think I'm using HDPI scaling. if you can get the program to load move around a bit then try. Problem occurs for me after I move around.

Comment: I checked my graphics in advanced display settings its Intel HD Graphics 520. Not sure if that's HDPI or not. but if so and if that is my problem how would i fix that in my game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that when you create a game with scrolling/camera/moving map, you're dealing with two different kinds of coordinates:

- the world coordinates (the *logical* coordinates, e.g. `(0, 0)` is always `(0, 0)`, no matter the scrolling/camera or map movement
- the screen coordinates (which you use to determine the actual position of something on the actual screen, e.g. `itemPos = (4,8)` is in world coordinates, and get's translated to screen coordinates by multiplying with 32: `(itemPos[0] * 32,itemPos[1] * 32)`.

So when you're reading the mouse position, you get screen coordinates. You have then to either translate them to world coordinates, or check it against the screen coordinates of your `item`.

You already to this here:

```
if mouse[0] > itemPos_rel[0] * 32 and mouse[0] < (itemPos_rel[0] * 32) + 32:
```

but you don't look at the scrolling/movement of your map.

So either translate the mouse position:

```
...
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse = mouse[0] - x, mouse[1] - y
...
```

or better (note that I don't change the background surface anymore):

```
...
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
i=0
def world2screen(pos, scrolling):
    return pos[0] * 32 + scrolling[0], pos[1] * 32 + scrolling[1]

while True:
    ...

    screen.blit(world, (x,y))

    item_pos_screen = world2screen(itemPos, (x, y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (*item_pos_screen,20,20))

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if mouse[0] > item_pos_screen[0] and mouse[0] < item_pos_screen[0] + 32:
        if mouse[1] > item_pos_screen[1] and mouse[1] < item_pos_screen[1] + 32:
            i+=1
            print("Mouse is over item" + str(i))


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

or event better:

```
...
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
i=0
def world2screen(pos, scrolling):
    return pos[0] * 32 + scrolling[0], pos[1] * 32 + scrolling[1]

def screen2world(pos, scrolling):
    return int((pos[0] - scrolling[0]) / 32), int((pos[1] - scrolling[1]) / 32 )

while True:
    ...
    screen.blit(world, (x,y))

    item_pos_screen = world2screen(itemPos, (x, y))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), (*item_pos_screen,20,20))

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_pos_world = screen2world(mouse, (x, y))

    if mouse_pos_world == itemPos:
        i+=1
        print("Mouse is over item" + str(i))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I get the same error. I bypass it by defining another list called `itemPos_rel`. I move the relative position of the item based on the key presses. This is not an elegant solution and I believe there are better ways of doing this. But maybe its useful to you for now.

```py
import pygame
import sys
import time

width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
world = pygame.Surface((20 * 32, 40 * 32))
itemPos = (4,8)
itemPos_rel = [4,8] ## Add relative item position
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(40):
        pygame.draw.rect(world, (255,0,0), (x * 32,y * 32,32,32), 2)
x,y = 0,0
while True:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            break
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        y += 10
        itemPos_rel[1] += 10/32
    if key[pygame.K_s]:
        y -= 10
        itemPos_rel[1] -= 10/32
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        x += 10
        itemPos_rel[0] += 10/32
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        x -= 10
        itemPos_rel[0] -= 10/32
    screen.blit(world, (x,y))
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    pygame.draw.rect(world, (0,255,0), (itemPos[0] * 32,itemPos[1] * 32,20,20))
    if mouse[0] > itemPos_rel[0] * 32 and mouse[0] < (itemPos_rel[0] * 32) + 32:
        if mouse[1] > itemPos_rel[1] * 32 and mouse[1] < (itemPos_rel[1] * 32) + 32:
            print(time.perf_counter(), "Mouse is over item")
    pygame.display.update()
```

I tested it with python 3.7.1 and pygame 1.9.5.